# WCF TCP session open in a PERCALL service?

Tags: wcf, service, tcp

I encountered the issue, that when I call a service from a client, without closing or disposing the client, the service does not respond after a (almost) same amount of calls.

The contract is set to

```
[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Allowed)]
```

The method is set to

```
[OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
```

The service is set to

```
[ServiceLocatorBehavior]
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single)]
```

Is it possible, that the "network session" of the TCP endpoint remains alive, even if the service is PERCALL (will be disposed, not reused like a session) and the method ISONEWAY?

Comment: The client was not disposed because of a "failure". After disposing the client, the service did work properly!

Comment: If your question is answered, please put the solution as an answer and mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client was not disposed because of a "failure". After disposing the client, the service did work properly!